# Is "I don't know what am I supposed to say" correct?

Tags: embedded-clauses

Is the following sentence correct?

> I don't know what am I supposed to say.

I feel like it's false according to embedded question grammar, but my friend keeps telling me that its correct 
what do you think?

Comment: Maybe your friend meant "I don't know. What am I supposed to say?" If you say it quickly it might seem like the way you wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

We call it inversion. This is an embedded question that is used as a subordinate clause rather than as the main clause of the sentence.

The correct version of your sentence is:

> I don't know what I am supposed to say.

Answer (score 0):

We reverse the order of a verb and a subject ***to form a question.***

> What **am I** supposed to say?

But, in your case, it's *not* a question. So, the order should remain standard (subject + verb)

> I don't know what **I am** supposed to say.